# Lost Crypt key of magento 2

Tags: configuration, magento2, magento2.2

I lost crypt key from my magento2 setup and now I am having issues with the PayPal and other configurations. Can somebody help me how I can recover crypt key via server?

Comment: Have you got the solution?

Answer (score 0):

On your server navigate to `app/etc` and open `env.php` file.

in `env.php` file you can find crypt key.

```
'crypt' => 
 array (
   'key' => '5b581cc9b27c0c114ed642a27d50c18c',
 )
```

Comment: Env.php file was deleted by mistake i somehow mangae to add the file but as crypt key is unique and paypal and customer credentials linked to the crypt key.